# Footer value for dynamic table - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

From JAVA backend API I am getting this response.

```
[
    [
        {
            "cardType": null,
            "cardDescText": "DISC      ",
            "dueToday": "1",
            "dueTomorrow": "0",
            "due2Days": "1",
            "due3Days": "0",
            "due4Days": "1",
            "due5Days": "11",
            "due6Days": "6",
            "due7Days": "1",
            "due8To15Days": "3",
            "due16PlusDays": "2",
            "total": "26",
            "msg": null,
            "tableName": null
        },
        {
            "cardType": null,
            "cardDescText": "Grand Total",
            "dueToday": "1",
            "dueTomorrow": "0",
            "due2Days": "1",
            "due3Days": "0",
            "due4Days": "1",
            "due5Days": "11",
            "due6Days": "6",
            "due7Days": "1",
            "due8To15Days": "3",
            "due16PlusDays": "2",
            "total": "26",
            "msg": null,
            "tableName": null
        }
    ]
]
```

We have created a dynamic mat table in our project. So in the above JSON data where-ever the "cardDescText": "Grand Total" is there I want to keep that inside footer of mat table.

Comment: Could you please show what code you have written currently, so will be easy to tell the required update?

Comment: And where is the problem? What have you tried so far

Comment: the above data i am excepting as row in response and passing that data as dataSource of angular table material. But the cardDescText : GrandTotal I want to separate out and keep that array inside footerArray.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate data cell in the table for footer like this:

```
<td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> Grand Total </td>
```

Have a look at this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/bynvnlvvbkm?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-footer-row-example.ts)

It's from the official [angular material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)